# How to get the closest particular div?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

What I want to do is when the user clicks on a color(div.colour_palette_box) I want to update Big Box(div.region). Problem is code should be dynamic since I have several set(div.color_set). One of them are shown below.

This is the UI which I'm referring to,

[image]

In fire bug it will look like this below.

[image]

What I tried up to now is.

```
jQuery('div#color_wrapper').on('click','div.colour_palette_box',function(){
        //jQuery(this).closest('div.region');
            //jQuery(this).prev('div.region');
            //both does not work

    });
```

Above code does not get me the closest div.region to the clicked div.colour_palette_box ? How can I get it ?

Update

Actual HTML

```
<div class="color_set">
   <div class="region">
      <div colorpalette="colour_selection_box_bg" class="colour_box"></div>
      <p>Product Background</p>
   </div>
   <div class="colour_selection_box_bg colorpalette" style="display: block;">
      <img src="components/com_jink/assets/images/close_mark.jpg" class="colorpalette_close" />
      <div class="colour_palette">
         <div colorid="6" colorregion="bgcolor" style="background:#000000" class="colour_palette_box"></div>
         <div colorid="7" colorregion="bgcolor" style="background:#00FF00" class="colour_palette_box"></div>
         <div colorid="8" colorregion="bgcolor" style="background:#0000FF" class="colour_palette_box"></div>
         <div colorid="9" colorregion="bgcolor" style="background:#FF0000" class="colour_palette_box"></div>
         <div colorid="10" colorregion="bgcolor" style="background:#FFFF00" class="colour_palette_box"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Better post your actual HTML code, not a screenshot, and a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: question has been updated as requested.

Comment: I think you'll need to take jQuery(this).parent().parent().prev('div.region') or something like that

Comment: `div.region` is not an ancestor of `div.colour_palette_box`, that's why `.closest` does not work.

Comment: @Alexandre Lavoie : Thanks if you can post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery('div#color_wrapper').on('click', 'div.colour_palette_box', function() {
    var bgColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    $(this).closest("div.colorpalette").prev("div.region").css("background-color", bgColor);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
jQuery('div#color_wrapper').on('click','div.colour_palette_box',function(){
    jQuery(this).parents("div.color_set").find("div.region")
                .css("background", jQuery(this).css("background"));
});
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

You need to get in the same parent to use .prev() so use this code :

```
jQuery(this).parent().parent().prev('div.region')
```

Answer (score 0):

`region` is a sibling of the parents of `box` so since it isn't an ancestor `closest` won't work

try:

```
$('.colour_palette_box').closest('.colorpalette').siblings('.region')
```